# creating a platform independent GUI executable in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

i have an ex.py file written in python using tkinter .i want to create an executable which can run on any platform.not creating separate executable for each platform(Linux,windows,Mac).

Comment: Pretty sure this is impossible.

Comment: As Kevin noted this isn't possible. If this really is big concert you may want to look into Jython. Java runs everywhere (ehm, sort of).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this. This is partly why interpreted languages like python exist: you write a platform-agnostic program that can run on any platform (in python, tcl, ruby, groovy, javascript, etc), then run it with a platform-specific runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @david I will look into jython.